# Print something to the console but it's not showing up in codewar (python)

Tags: python, debugging

In codewar, I was doing the [Codewars style ranking system](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51fda2d95d6efda45e00004e/train/python) exercise and failed passing the "attempt". I want to print the input to the console for debugging, however it shows up in some test cases while not in other cases.

I have tried flushing the stdout acoording to the [instruction](https://docs.codewars.com/training/troubleshooting/#print-output) but nothing changes.
[image]
This is my code(you can see the `print(something)` code in line 8):

```py
import sys
class User:
    def __init__(self, rank=-8, progress=0) -> None:
        self.rank = rank
        self.progress = progress
    def inc_progress(self, rank):
        if rank == 0 or rank < -8 or rank > 8:
            raise Exception("Invalid input")
        print(self.rank, self.progress) 
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if self.rank < 0 and rank > 0 :
            diff = rank - self.rank - 1
        elif self.rank > 0 and rank < 0:
            diff = rank - self.rank + 1
        else:
            diff = rank - self.rank
        if diff == 0:
            earning = 3
        elif diff == -1:
            earning = 1
        elif diff <= -2:
            earning = 0
        else:
            earning = 10*diff*diff
        q, r = divmod(self.progress + earning, 100)
        self.progress = r
        if q >= 1 and self.rank+q >= 0 and self.rank<0:
            self.rank = min(self.rank + q + 1, 8)
        else:
            self.rank = min(8, self.rank+q)
```

Comment: Now I realized the bug is forgetting resetting the progress value to zero when rank is bigger than 8. But the printing failure definitely make the debugging much more annoying. I still don't know why.